# Typescript - define type for irregular object structure

Tags: typescript

I would like to properly type my `Comparator` object which has following structure:

```
const Comparator: ComparatorType = {
  string: {
    equals: function(a: string, b: string) {...},
    notEquals: function(a: string, b: string) {...},
    contains: function(a: string, b: string) {...}
    ...

  },
  number: {
    equals: function(a: number, b: number) {...},
    lowerThan: function(a: number, b: number) {...},
    greaterThan: function(a: number, b: number) {...}
    ...
  },
  datetime: {...}
}
```

So as you can see some functions are common for multiple data types (like `equal`) but others are unique. I was able to come up with:

```
type DataType = "string" | "integer" | "datetime"
type Operation = "equals" | "notEquals" | "contains" | "notContains" | ...

// and define functions:
type CompareStringCommonFunc = (
  a: string,
  b: string
) => boolean

type CompareIntegerCommonFunc = (
  a: number,
  b: number
) => boolean

...others...
```

So I could finally come up with `ComparatorType` like this:

```
type ComparatorType = {
  [dataType in DataType]: {
    [funcName in Operation]:
      | CompareStringCommonFunc
      | CompareStringInFunc
      | CompareStringBetweenFunc
      | CompareIntegerCommonFunc
      | CompareIntegerBetweenFunc
      | CompareIntegerInFunc
  }
}
```

But it obviously doesn't work as the `Comparator` is not regular (I mean each `DataType` doesn't have all `Operation`s) and my typescript knowledge is not so deep yet to figure it out on my own. How can I solve it so I can assign for example for `string` `DataType` only few `Operation` values with specific functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say just keep things simple. It complicates things to try and "map" types and values to more complicated structures, especially when the names, numbers, and types of functions will differ for every "type". You could just define your `ComparatorType` more explicitly:

```
type CompareFn<T> = (a: T, b: T) => void;

type ComparatorType = {
    string: {
        equals: CompareFn<string>,
        notEquals: CompareFn<string>,
        contains: CompareFn<string>
    },
    number: {
        equals: CompareFn<number>,
        lowerThan: CompareFn<number>,
        greaterThan: CompareFn<number>
    },
    // etc
}
```

Here `CompareFn` is just a generic utility type to streamline the definition of function types, which all seem to have the same arguments pattern just with different types.

You can still have a type `DataType` if you want, by reverse engineering the keys of this type: `type DataType = keyof ComparatorType;`.  Reverse engineering a generic `Operation` type is more difficult, however, because the keys `equals`, `notEquals` etc are not consistent between "types" of your `ComparatorType`. But you can still easily get the keys associated with the specific types with something like `keyof ComparatorType['string']`, `keyof ComparatorType['number']` etc.